проблемы password_verify
Никак не могу добиться, чтоб функция вернула true,проверил все вводы в базу данных, хэши совпадают, при выгрузке из базы данных он тоже правильный
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
echo "$password";
// Подключение к базе данных
include 'connect.php';

// Подготовленный запрос к базе данных
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE name = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// Проверка на успешность подготовленного запроса
if ($stmt) {
    // Привязка параметров к запросу
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);

    // Выполнение запроса
    $stmt->execute();

    // Получение результата
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // Проверка на успешность выполнения запроса и наличие результатов
    if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        // Проверяем соответствие пароля
        if (password_verify($password, $row['password_hash'])) {
            header("Location: dashboard.php");
            exit(); 
        } else {
            // Если пароль не соответствует, выводим сообщение об ошибке
            echo "Неверный пароль";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Пользователь с именем $name не найден";
    }

    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo "Ошибка при подготовке запроса: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
}
?> 

вот код для записи в БД
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Хэширование пароля
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo "$hashed_password";

// Подготавливаем SQL запрос для добавления нового администратора в базу данных
$sql = "INSERT INTO admin (name, password_hash) VALUES (?, ?)";

// Подготавливаем запрос
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// Привязываем параметры
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $hashed_password);


$row['password_hash'] выдает правильный хэш, является ли хэш $password аналогичным хэшу из базы данных функция и должна проверить, я не могу сам сравнить хэши, потому как у них будут разные соли

можете показать сначала $hashed_password и как вы его храните в базе данных?

@YaMus password_hash хранится как varchar 255

а вы не пробовали поменять алгоритм на PASSWORD_BCRYPT?

Хоть камрад @YaMus и верит в чудеса, их на самом деле не бывает. Вот онлайн шелл, https://phpize.online/. Показывайте, что у вас там "не возвращает true". И заодно попробуйте объяснить, почему вы не выводите на экран полученный из базы хэш, и как вы в таком случае узнали, что он "совпадает".

Код в принципе неплохой для новичка, но из него надо убрать весь мусор. Почему это был мусор, прочитать здесь: https://habr.com/ru/articles/662523/
